# How to read multiple I2C sensor (MLX90393) data on ESP32?

Tags: sensor, i2c, esp8266, hall-effect, graph

I am using [MLX90393](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/e/e/f/2/7/MLX90393-Datasheet-Melexis.PDF) Triaxial Magnetometer Sensors for my project. They communicate via I2C. I am using an ESP32 and coding on Arduino IDE. I found this code on [GITHUB](https://github.com/ControlEverythingCommunity/MLX90393/blob/master/Arduino/MLX90393.ino) and was able to read from ONE sensor successfully. However, I am doing a project to use FOUR of these sensors. My sensors have a custom-made PCB board and I am aware that each sensor have different addresses (manually configured through soldering). I am also using 2 pull up resistors to get reading from ONE sensor, which I am only able to do until now.

However, I am struggling to understand how the code works and as a result not able to change it accordingly to make TWO or FOUR of these sensors work together. My goal is to keep reading data simultaneously from FOUR sensors via I2C (SDA,SCL,Vcc,Gnd), transfer the readings over Wi-Fi and finally, once one of the four sensors is touched, display data from that specific sensor only.

Also, if you know a good way to visualize X,Y,Z axis data, please do suggest.

Thank you in advance for your kind help.

Comment: As Elliot says you can use A0 and A1 (Vcc/Gnd) to place 4 devices at 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E and 0x0F.  However, you cannot access them **simultaneously**.

Answer (score 1):

This is discussed at the beginning of section 8.4 in the linked datasheet.

Basically, you need to use two pins on the MLX90393 to set the two least significant address bits of the I2C interface. Wire your four devices so that they have four different values for these two bits/pins. As a result, the four devices will have unique addresses on the I2C bus.

In your code, change the slave address for the I2C commands in order to talk to the different devices.

Comment: Yep, already changed the addresses of the individual sensor, scanned for their addresses to find their correct address. I individually tried the different sensors using their known addresses and could read data successfully. But when I try to call it using their addresses, two simultaneously, then neither is being read.

Comment: Ah, well you should probably have included that information more clearly in your question and also explained exactly what you meant by "simultaneously".

Answer (score 0):

Reading from 4 devices simultaneously with 1 i2C master is not possible.
From just looking at the code form Github and you have a different address for each device. The simplest to try is the following ( pseudo code).

A good way to look at it is to run that code for each address.

````
#include<Wire.h>

// MLX90393 I2C Address is 0x0C(12)
#define Addr0 0x0A  //fictional
#define Addr1 0x0B  //fictional
#define Addr2 0x0C  //fictional
#define Addr3 0x0D  //fictional

void setup() 
{
  // Initialise I2C communication as MASTER 
  Wire.begin();
  // Initialise serial communication, set baud rate = 9600
  Serial.begin(9600);

  run setup code for ALL addresses
  Wire.beginTransmission(Addr0);
  ..........setup code
  Wire.beginTransmission(Addr1);
  ..........setup code
  Wire.beginTransmission(Addr2);
  ..........setup code
  Wire.beginTransmission(Addr3);
  ..........setup code
}

void loop() 
{

  run same code for all addresses

}


```
````

Comment: That would have been my first guess so already tried that but when I try this, I don't get any data from either sensors. Maybe there is some issue with setup code but not sure what they do.